# The authorization grant is invalid

Tags: api, authorization, pinterest

"message": "The authorization grant is invalid"
i cannot find any solution for me.someone say that app id need to approve. someone say no need to. what i am doing wrong. How to authorized the collaborators to my app. i add 2 developers and one tester.

when i try to authorized to my self from this url and others(my collaborators)

https://api.pinterest.com/oauth/?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44371/auth/pinterest/callback/&client_id=[api_id]&scope=write_public&state=768uyFys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure about the following:

1. redirect_uri specified in request is same as specified in app configuration
2. webserver is running as specified by redirect_uri and can handle this uri as it will get authorization_code which then further has to be used for access_token.

Hope this helps.

Comment: my redirect_uri is same.  now i get the code from same url. thanks for your reply. i don't know why i get this code i have nothing change.

Comment: @Anil: Typically authorization_code will have validity. After authorization_code validity is expired then you should use refresh token to get new authorization_code and also a new refresh_token. This way app maintains valid and up to data authorization_code.